# Wunderground Geolocation using $.ajax not appending to HTML

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, geolocation

I am experimenting using in using $.ajax to use geolocation to input weather data into a page from Wunderground.  I am able to successfully input weather data into my page when I manually enter my location into code using plain vanilla JS but want to take it a step further.  I am running the following code and get an alert box asking for location but after clicking okay see no code updates to my HTML.  When opening the console in dev tools I do not see any error messages.

```
var Geo={};
if (navigator.geolocation) {
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(successGeo,error);
}
else {
alert('Geolocation is not supported');
}

function error() {
alert("Cant find you");
}

function successGeo(position) {
      Geo.lat = position.coords.latitude;
      Geo.lng = position.coords.longitude;
}

function showPosition(position) {
    var geoLat = position.coords.latitude;
    var geoLong = position.coords.longitude;
    var key = "8704dded63fc077d";
    var ForecastURL = "http://api.wunderground.com/api/"; + key + "/forecast/q/" + geoLat + "," + geoLong + ".json";
    var WeatherURL = "http://api.wunderground.com/api/"; + key + "/conditions/q/" + geoLat + "," + geoLong + ".json";




  $.ajax({
        url : WeatherURL,
        dataType : "jsonp",
        success : function(parsed_json) {
        var temp_f = parsed_json['current_observation']['temp_f'];
        document.getElementById("currentTemp").innerHTML = temp_f;
        }
    });

  $.ajax({
        url : ForecastURL,
        dataType : "jsonp",
        success : function(parsed_json) {
        var fore_high = parsed_json['forecast']['simpleforecast']['forecastday'][0]['high']['fahrenheit'];
        var fore_low = parsed_json['forecast']['simpleforecast']['forecastday'][0]['low']['fahrenheit'];
        document.getElementById("high1").innerHTML = fore_high;
        document.getElementById("low1").innerHTML = fore_low;

        }
    });    

} //ends showposition function
```

I have some div elements set up in the footer of index.html just so I can confirm the elements are being updated.  I'll worry more about style and alignment later.

```
<footer> <!--//contains ajax weather data-->
<div id="high1"></div>
<div id="current_temp"></div>
<div id="low1"></div>
</footer>
```

I'm pretty stumped as to why I can't get a response, especially since I'm not picking up any errors in the console.

Comment: Where / when do you call `showPosition`? So far you have `getCurrentPosition` doing a callback to `successGeo`, not `showPosition`

Comment: Good catch. I had some old code and in the process of copying and pasting forgot to change my function names and when they are called. Thanks for the help.  Also realized I have an extra ";" in my concatenation when declaring ForecastURL and WeatherURL variables.